# Sorting form fields based on width change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I have a calculation form on my website which contains 3 fields.

While viewing the form on a PC the fields are in a correct horizontal order of 3,2,1 (RTL form)

But if i View the page on mobile, the fields appear vertically, which is fine. but the order is backwards:

```
3
2
1
```

How can i change the order using JS based on the page width?

[The Form](http://theonebracelet.com/?lfb_action=preview&form=4)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id='parent'>
      <div order="1">A</div>
      <div order="2">B</div>
      <div order="3">C</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

js:

```
  var parent = $('#parent');
  var child = parent.find('div');
  // if window size smaller than 480, reverse the order
  if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
      child.sort(function(a, b) {
          return b.getAttribute('order') - a.getAttribute('order');
      }).appendTo($('#parent'));
  }
```

you can resize the window and run the script

if width < 480, order will reverse

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tehurotiza/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to go around this by using CSS:

```
    @media (max-width: 480px) 
{
    .row
    {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
```